# What is the alternative for toObservable?

Tags: jquery, rxjs

I am trying to use RxJS, but the example I got is a little old.
The code I need to run is this:

```
myInput.toObservable("keyup")
        .Throttle(200)
        .Subscribe(function () {
```

but `toObservable` has been removed.
My research didn't help. I even found this post requesting `toObservable` 's return, but no explanation of the alternative.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery/issues/4

Does anyone know what is the alternative for `toObservable`?

Comment: As it says in your link, you can use `.bindAsObservable` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very complete example of using the jQuery extensions for rxjs [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery) that accomplishes something very similar to what you want:

```
var throttledInput = myInput
    .keyupAsObservable()
    .select( function (ev) {
        return $(ev.target).val();
    })
    .throttle(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged();
```

You should be able to `subscribe` to the result and perform whatever you'd like then.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at the link, because I got no success with `keyupAsObservable()`. `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'keyupAsObservable'`  I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It's a separate library ... have you included it? (It's in the [source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery/blob/master/src/rx-jquery.js) still).

Comment: I did, when I checked the example I saw I was missing rx.time, still even though I added it the problem persists. I'll keep looking, since it's my first time it is very likely I'm missing something small :D

Comment: what is `myInput`? It would need to be a jQuery wrapped element. (And there's a complete example [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery/blob/master/examples/Autocomplete.html)

Comment: It is, but now it's working... the problem was my jQuery version. Thanks for your help. (keyupAsObservable is working now) :)